# Google chrome graphical issue rendering black squares

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

When I start google chrome, the graphics does not render the way it should. Why is it looking like this and what can be done about it?

[image]

Comment: Does this only happen with Chrome? When did it start doing this?

Comment: @Jack Yes it happens only with chrome. It started when I upgraded to Windows 10. I have reinstalled chrome but the issue is stille there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem on OS X, so it can be related to a memory corruption or a graphic card driver issue.

You can simply quit the web browser and start again. If won't help, try restarting your machine.

Then try upgrading your Chrome (you may also try beta version).

If this happens too often, [check the Chrome logs](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) or increase your verbosity level further more to track the problem.

Then once you find the relevant errors, either [check existing bugs, report a new bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) or check mine: [Issue 523559](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=523559) (if you think it's the same).

However yours look like the whole window is scrambled, so either it's a memory leak, graphic card driver issue (try upgrading it), you're out of memory or disk space or its Windows issue it-self.

Answer (score 0):

It helped me turn off hardware acceleration
https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-enable-disable-hardware-acceleration-mode

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1117867)